# Reference a hidden column in a calculated column

Tags: 2010, site-column, calculated-column, hidden

In SharePoint 2010, I have a document library in which I want to add a calculated column, which references the Name of the document. Entering the following formula works fine:

```
=[Title]
```

But I can't seem to be able to reference the [Name] field - I'm guessing because it is hidden?  i.e. entering any of the following formulas:

```
=[Name]
=[LinkFilename]
=[BaseName]
=[NameOrTitle]
```

Causes:

> The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula
>   for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing
>   column

The only thing I can think of is somehow making the Name field unhidden - but this feels a very dangerous thing to do fiddling around with system columns. Does anyone know of another way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use the 'Name' column in calculated columns. It's not because it's hidden, though as the 'ID' column is hidden as well but can be used in calculations. I think it has more to do with the fact that 'Name' is specific to document libraries rather than all lists. You can use a workflow or event handler to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I should have asked...what are you trying to do with the Name field that made you opt for using a Calculated field in the first place?  Maybe one of us can throw out another idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name isn't Hidden and even if it was, tinkering with OOB fields is not advisable.

It's not allowing it because it's type is File.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So, what I want to do is reference the name of the document (i.e. the name of the .doc file stored in the Name field) in the calculated column. If I can't use the Name field (and I don't want to use the Title field either) can you think of any way to get to the name of the file in the calculation? Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I can't...any field that could contain the name (EncodedAbsUrl, ServerUrl, Name, LinkName, etc.) are all off limits in a calculated field.  You'd have to do it in a workflow, write a custom SPField, or event receiver.

Comment: Great idea with the workflow / event reciever! I'll think I'll try that. Thanks Rob